# Changing parts of compiled binaries

Tags: c++, c, assembly, binary, patch

*learned english as a second lang, sorry for the mistakes & awkwardness*

I have given a peculiar project to work on. The company has lost the source code for the app, and I have to make changes to it. Now, reverse engineering the whole thing is impossible for one man, its just too huge, however patching individual functions would be feasible, since the changes are not that monumental.

So, one possible solution would be compiling C code and somehow -after rewriting addresses- patching it into the actual binary, ideally, replacing the code the CALL instruction jumps to, or inserting a JMP to my code.

Is there any way to accomplish this using MingW32? If it is, can you provide a simple example? I'm also interested in books which could help me accomplishing the task.

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: Oh my god. Your company _lost the source code_? I think you're asking the wrong question my friend.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: You might be surprised how much mission critical software is running without the source being accessible anymore; hard drives die, backup tapes rot, physical formats change, and "this is just a quick hack that we'll rebuild properly next week" is an all too common attitude. +1 for the "oh my god" anyway.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: In the company I work for there is a non-critical piece of software still being used that was compiled with Clipper Summer'87 and that was written long before I got there by someone that wasn't working for them any more. I did a full scan of all the source code backups they had but there are messages on the screen that are in none of the source files. I found several copies of the sources (in directories named "last", "good", "final", "old", "working" and the like) but none of them is the is the source of the executable in production.

Comment: The more reason to use open source, and let everybody mirror it.

Comment: @user611775: I don't understand - is that an answer to the specific question?

Answer (score 2):

I use [OllyDBG](http://www.ollydbg.de/) for this kind of things. It allows you to see the disassembly and debug it, you can place breakpoints etc, and you can also edit the binary. So, you could edit the PE header of that program adding a code section with *your* (compiled) code inside, then call it from the original program.
I can't give you any advice since I've never tried, although I thought about it many times. You know, lazyness.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would disassemble the program with a high-quality disassembler that produces something that can be assembled back into a runnable app, and then replace the parts you need to modify with C code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will let you reverse the machine code into source.  It won't be pretty but it does work.

http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/

There are also tools for runtime patching http://www.dyninst.org/ for instance. They really aren't made for patching but they can do the trick.

And of course the last choice is to just use an assembler and write machine code :)