# Adding a function to a Linux binary

Tags: binary, patch

as part of a homework assignment for my security class, I'm supposed to "add a simple function which prints "Hello, World!" to a compiled C Linux binary". The binary provided is just a compiled `main` function with 10 `NOP`s in it.

Normally, I would have written the code needed into the `NOP` section directly, but we were explicitly told to add a new function to the program.

I have no idea how to do that. I tried putting some code at the end of the binary, but this seems to destroy it. Could somebody clear this up for me?

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059930/changing-parts-of-compiled-binaries) sounds somewhat similar.

EDIT 2: Searching for "ELF injection" yields many interesting results.

Comment: Looks like they want you to place a call to your added funtion in the main. So make a source with main with call plus your hello and then look at the bytes.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Is it that easy? From looking at the bytes, I gather that there's a lot more stored in binary than just the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to learn more about [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (espacially if you want to make a program able to "infect" any Linux binary, not just the simple one you've got).

The Linux ABI [X86-64 supplement](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html) could also be useful, and also the [Linux Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)

Comment: Can you recommend any good tutorials (possibly even directly related to my question)?

Comment: I don't understand if you just want to solve your problem once for the particular binary you've got (then, a simple hex editor is enough; but you need to understand the ELF executable, and `objdump` should help a lot) or if you claim to make a sort of virus able to modify any Linux ELF executable.

Comment: For now I'm just trying to solve the problem for  the particular binary, although the goal of the assignment is of course to really understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could end the main function, and then start a new function in the NOPs -- but before ending the main function, call the new function you have added after the end of the main function.

Comment: This limits the new function's size though, doesn't it. I think the idea of adding a new function vs. just overwriting the `NOP`s is that the new function _could_ be larger than the `NOP`s available...